# Prolog recursion: extracting wanted result

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to create a predicate in Prolog that applies another predicate to all elements in a given list:

```
take_items(_,[],_).
take_items(Stock,[Item|BTail],_) :-
    take_item(Stock,Item,Updates),
    take_items(Updates,BTail,Updates).
```

FYI: I am using SWI-Prolog.
When in trace mode I can see that it indeed does what I want it to, but then starts backtracking. Here is the trace output from where it hits the base case to end:

```
   Call: (8) take_items([item(a, 2), item(b, 1)], [], [item(a, 2), item(b, 1)]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) take_items([item(a, 2), item(b, 1)], [], [item(a, 2), item(b, 1)]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) take_items([item(a, 2), item(b, 3)], [item(b, 2)], [item(a, 2), item(b, 3)]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) take_items([item(a, 3), item(b, 3)], [item(a, 1), item(b, 2)], _G1991) ? creep
true .
```

How do I get it to output `X = [list, of, items]` when calling`take_items([first,list],[second,list],X).`?

Comment: What's the point of the third parameter, if both clauses ignore it?

Comment: Please forgive me if this seems very silly. I am new to Prolog.
The third parameter is where the wanted result is dumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
take_items(_,[],[]).
take_items(Stock,[Item|BTail],[Update|Updates]) :-
    take_item(Stock,Item,Update),
    take_items(Updates,BTail,Updates).
```

> I am trying to create a predicate in Prolog that applies another predicate to all elements in a given list:

actually, there is maplist/3 available

```
take_items(Stock,Items,Updates) :- maplist(take_item(Stock),Items,Updates).
```

Comment: I used your first solution, with the first parameter of the recursive take_items call as Update instead of Updates. The third parameter then contains the list of steps to the result. In order to extract the final step, I used the "last" predicate to get the final step when using the take_items predicate.